# AppleScript to move files to correct location

Tags: applescript

**Goal:**

I am trying to write a script that I can tie into a folder action to move files from a download folder to the proper location. The folder will see music, movies and TV shows, or sports. There will be individual files as well as folders of multiple items. I have the skeleton of the script done, but I'm struggling with a few things that I know how to do in other languages.

**Parameters:**

TV: S%%E%% for individual files & S%% for folders

Movies: Folders with a single video file(mkv, mp4, m4v) and no S%%E%% in name, or folders without S%%

Audio: File type (mp3, aac, flac, wav) for individual files, folders will be tough seeing the contents

**Issues:**

How do I change the file selection to include folders and files for testing? I think this will work fine when I am giving the script input from a folder action in Automator, but not entirely sure yet.

It seems there are not wildcards available in Applescript to use in my comparisons.

My main issue is not knowing how to open a folder item and loop through the contents looking for certain extensions or names.

**GitHub:https://github.com/wiebs2334/DownloadManager**

Any suggestions or advice would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vanilla AppleScript is not able to handle wildcards for text search but there is a free Scripting Addition `Satimage.osax` which adds powerful functions for example find text with Regular Expression

You can find the OSAX on the [Smile Companion OSAX](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/downloads/downloads_companion_osaxen.html) site. Download `Satimage osax 3.7.0 (build 411)` and put the file into `/Library/ScriptingAdditions` (top level `Library`!)

This is your optimized script using the Scripting Addition, the basic regex patterns are

- `"\\.S\\d{2}E"`: Look for a dot follows by capital `S` followed by two digits and a captital `E`
- `"(nhl|nfl|ncaa)"` : Text contains "nhl" or "nfl" or "ncaa"

If the text doesn't match the pattern an error is thrown.

---

The major changes are

- The `run` handler shows a dialog to select files or folders
- The `open` handler is added to use the script as droplet
- Your `if/end if - if/end if` expressions are replaced with `if/else if/end if`

If your are going to use the script as folder action both files and folders are considered anyway

---

```
property audioKeywords : {"mp3", "aac", "flac", "wav"}
property videoExtensions : {"mkv", "m4v", "mov", "mp4"}

on run
    set {button returned:buttonReturned} to display dialog "Choose files or folders" buttons {"Cancel", "Choose Files", "Choose Folders"}
    if buttonReturned is "Choose Files" then
        classifyItems for (choose file with multiple selections allowed)
    else
        classifyItems for (choose folder with multiple selections allowed)
    end if

end run

on open theItems
    classifyItems for theItems
end open

to classifyItems for myFiles
    repeat with anItem in myFiles
        set anItem to anItem as text
        set isVideo to false
        set isTV to false
        set isMovie to false
        set isAudio to false
        set isSports to false
        tell application "System Events" to set {theClass, theName, theExt, theContainer} to {class, name, name extension, container} of disk item anItem --set variables
        set className to theClass as text
        (*  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&  Files  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& *)
        if className is "file" then
            ###########  Video ############
            if theExt is in videoExtensions then --search through all video extensions
                set isVideo to true
                ###########  TV ############
                try
                    find text "\\.S\\d{2}E" in theName with regexp
                    set isTV to true
                on error
                    ###########  Sports ############
                    try
                        find text "(nhl|nfl|ncaa)" in theName with regexp
                        set isSports to true
                    on error
                        ###########  Movies ############
                        set isMovie to true
                    end try
                end try
                ###########  Audio ############
            else if theExt is in audioKeywords then
                set isAudio to true
            end if

            (*  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&  Folders  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& *)
        else if className is "folder" then
            ###########  TV ############
            try
                find text "\\.S\\d{2}\\." in theName with regexp
                set isTV to true
            on error
                try
                    ###########  Audio ############
                    find text "(mp3|aac|flac|wav)" in theName with regexp
                    set isAudio to true
                on error
                    ###########  Movie ############
                    set isMovie to true
                end try
            end try
        end if

        display dialog ("Type:" & theClass & " || Ext:" & theExt & " || Video:" & isVideo & "
        " & theName & "
        Movie:" & isMovie & " || TV:" & isTV & " || Sports:" & isSports & "
        Audio:" & isAudio)

    end repeat
end classifyItems
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I needed! Would you know how in the folder section of my code I can go a level deeper to do these same searches on the files as well? Then I'd be able to more reliably tell what type of folder I'm looking at. There are a decent number of times that the folder name won't have any keywords in it but the files will.

Comment: Basically you can call the handler recursively. In the folder branch get all items of the folder as alias list and call `to classifyItems` again.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot. I tried a different way, but it was failing. This seems easier and more efficient.

Comment: I got that part working, but when I was testing the script hooked up to the folder action I had 5 ".m4v" files that wouldn't move when the script is tied to the folder action. I did dump 1000 files in for it to filter and move, but those 5 remained. The script isn't even triggering, since i put a display dialog in to test if it was running or not.

I tested the script through script editor as well and it moved those files no problem.